# Can Access External Website Sitemap.xml from my Browser, but not using cURL

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, amazon-ec2

I am trying to access an website's sitemap.xml file from a custom built wordpress plugin on an Amazon EC2 instance using PHP and cURL.
This website's sitemap.xml file only has 13 items and is a very small file.
When I type in "https://www.example.com/sitemap.xml" in my browser I am able to view the file. I have enabled "fopen" in my instance's php.ini file. My PHP code is very simple, but the script runs for a long time (several minutes) with no result and the error:

```
 TCP connection reset by peer

function getThisSiteMap(){
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.example.com/sitemap.xml');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36');
 $feed = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_error($ch)) {
    $error_msg = curl_error($ch);
    }
    $xmlTermsIR = simplexml_load_string($feed);

    if ($xmlTermsIR) {
       echo 'HEELLEOO';
    } else {
        echo 'NOT WORKING' . '<br>';
        echo $error_msg;
     }
    }
```

I am a little confused because I am able to access other sitemap.xml files using this same code. Do I need to use a different user agent? How can I use cURL to access this sitemap.xml? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would SSH into the server and see if you can simply:

```
curl https://www.example.com/sitemap.xml
```

This will tell you if it's a code issue or simply can't resolve the domain from the server. I would also try echo out $feed and omit simplexml_load_string(), just to see if it's hanging on the request.

You can also enable php logs and see if it's dying instead of completing with no output by putting the following at the top

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help iDanoo, I did SSH into the server and simply ran:                   
     curl https://www.example.com/sitemap.xml .     and it worked!!! So now I am really confused what the problem is!

Comment: Hmm I'd definitely try the error log approach then, see if anything gets output that may be helpful. If you add the above error code at the top of your PHP, it should output into /var/log/*.log somewhere depending on your php version.